# Why do my Slicers change behavior when adding a measure to the Pivot Table in a PowerPivot model?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, excel-2016, slicers

I am running `Excel 2016` and I have built a `PowerPivot` Model. 
On my `Pivot Table`, I have inserted 4 `slicers` namely: Market, Agency, Hotel, and WeekGroup.

All the relationships in the `PowerPivot` model have been correctly set up. Here is how the pivot table looks (when it has been filtered by some variables on the `Slicers`):

```
Row Labels    PickUp       PickUp (Same Period Last Year)
WeekGroup 10    160             388
Grand Total     160             388
```

The above has Hotel A selected on the `Slicer` Hotel. I have changed the Properties of all the `slicers` so that they hide items with no data.
With Hotel A selected, the `Slicer` Agency now shows ONLY the Agency names applicable for Hotel A and the period shown in the `pivot table`. So far, so good.

I have created a new `measure` which is basically the % change between PickUp and PickUp (Same Period Last Year). When I add this `Measure` to the `pivot table`, the `Slicer` Agency now shows the names of **ALL** agencies in the data source. The setting to hide items with no data seems to be overridden!

Is this normal behaviour or am I missing something here?

Comment: can you post the measure?

Comment: Post the DAX measure - and your model diagram view might be helpful